# Aligning arrow in accordion react native

Tags: react-native, styling

I am using https://github.com/dooboolab/dooboo-ui-native/tree/master/src/components/shared/Accordion library to do accordion for FAQ. 
I am trying to style the arrow on the right. I want it to be aligned on the same height as header. Any ideas? Or maybe do you recommend different libraries for this feature?

```
  export default styles = {
  accordion: {
    flex: 1
  },
  question: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  questionView: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  answer: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'justify'
  },
  answerView: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  icon: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  }
};
```

And the Accordion:

```
 return (
        <Accordion
          key={item.id}
          style={styles.accordion}
          contentVisible={false}
          visibleElement={
            <View style={styles.icon}>
              <Icon size={12} name="arrow-up" style={styles.icon} />
            </View>
          }
          invisibleElement={
            <View style={styles.icon}>
              <Icon size={12} name="arrow-down" />
            </View>
          }
          header={
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.question}>{item.item.question}</Text>
            </View>
          }
        >
          <View style={styles.answerView}>
            <Text style={styles.answer}>{item.item.answer}</Text>
          </View>
        </Accordion>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two solutions
1. Either you can use the style to set the arrow. It will be like this:

> position: 'absolute',
>   top: 0, right: 0

2. Or you should add the view which contains the ARROW in the header as well. In this case you will need to have a parent  VIEW with flexdirection set to row, and then two child VIEW, with one for header text and the other for Arrow.

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: You are most welcome :) .. If it did help you, can you please mark it as accepted answer so if someone else is facing the same issue can utilize this solution as well :). Thanks